# Python - Extract pattern from string using RegEx

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in variable `a` as below:

```
a = 'foo(123456) together with foo(2468)'
```

I would like to use "re" to extract both `foo(123456)` and `foo(2468)` from the string.

I have two questions:

1. What is the correct regex to be used? `foo(.\*)` doesn't seem to work, as it treats `123456)` together with `foo(2468` as `.*`
2. How to extract both foo?

Comment: You need a non-greedy version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'foo\(.*?\)')
test_str = 'foo(123456) together with foo(2468)'

for match in re.findall(pattern, test_str):
    print(match)
```

Two things:

1. `.*?` is the lazy quantifier. It behaves the same as the greedy quantifier (`.*`), except it tries to match the *least* amount of characters possible going from left-to-right across the string. Note that if you want to match at least one character between the parentheses, you'll want to use `.+?`.
2. Use `\(` and `\)` instead of `(` and `)` because parentheses are normally used inside regular expressions to indicate capture groups, so if you want to match parentheses literally, you have to use the escape character before them, which is backslash.

Answer (score 5):

You can use findall with the following expression: `r'(foo\(\d+\))'`:

```
import re

a = 'foo(123456) together with foo(2468)'

for v in re.findall(r'(foo\(\d+\))', a):
    print(v)
```

Result is:

```
foo(123456)
foo(2468)
```

Your expressoin `foo(.*)` does not work due to `()`. You need to escape them, as I did above.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin
What if my string is :
    a = 'foo(abcdef) together with foo(jqk)'
Which regex should I use?

Comment: Use same one but instead of `\d+` do as you did `.+`

Answer (score 4):

You could use a negated character class.

```
>>> a = 'foo(123456) together with foo(2468) foo(abcdef) together with foo(jqk)'
>>> re.findall(r'\bfoo\([^()]*\)', a)
['foo(123456)', 'foo(2468)', 'foo(abcdef)', 'foo(jqk)']
```

`[^()]*` negated character class which matches any character but not of `(` or `)`, zero or more times.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the non-greedy wildcard expression `.*?`

```
import re
a = 'foo(123456) together with foo(2468)'
for v in re.findall(r'foo\(.*?\)', a):
  print(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.findall(r'foo\(.*?\)')`. The backslashes escape the parentheses (which have a special meaning of denoting a group in regex), and the question mark makes the match be performed in a non-greedy manner.